# How to convert all string in Dart list to lowercase?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, lowercase

I want check if Dart list contain string with `list.contains` so must convert string in array to lowercase first.

How to convert all string in list to lowercase?

For example:

```
[example@example.com, Example@example.com, example@Example.com, example@example.cOm, EXAMPLE@example.cOm]
```

Comment: You can use .any() instead. 
if (["aBc", "bca"].any((el) => el.toLowerCase() == "abc")) print("contains");

Comment: Beware... the local part of the address (to the left of the @) might be _case-sensitive_ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807909/are-email-addresses-case-sensitive).  Although you probably won't run into issues, best to leave that alone if you can.

Answer (score 11):

You can map through the entire list and convert all the items to lowercase. Please see the code below.

```
  List<String> emails = ["example@example.com", "Example@example.com", "example@Example.com", "example@example.cOm", "EXAMPLE@example.cOm"];
  emails = emails.map((email)=>email.toLowerCase()).toList();
  print(emails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now with Dart you can use extension methods to do this kind of conversions

```
extension LowerCaseList on List<String> {
  void toLowerCase() {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      this[i] = this[i].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
}
```

When you import it, you can use it like

```
List<String> someUpperCaseList = ["QWERTY", "UIOP"];

someUpperCaseList.toLowerCase();

print(someUpperCaseList[0]); // -> qwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
List<String> emails = ["example@example.com", "Example@example.com", "example@Example.com", "example@example.cOm", "EXAMPLE@example.cOm"];
 for(String email in emails){
  print(email.toLowerCase());
}
```