# How do I create a list of emails from first name, last name and city?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, dbeaver

To clarify the question:
I have a table with customers which includes the first_name and last_name and the address_id. Now I have to create a list of new emails which are made of the first name and last name and the city:
firstname.lastname@city.com
I am using the sakila database btw if that is of any help
Could anybody explain to me, how I can accomplish this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customer table has the first and last name, but not the city.
It has an address_id though, so we can join to the address table.

The address table doesn't have the city name either, but it has a city_id.
So we join the city table to the address table.

Now with the required parts available, the new email can be constructed.

```
select replace(
          lower(
             concat(cust.first_name, '.', cust.last_name, '@', city.city, '.com')
          ), ' ', '_') as new_email
from customer cust
join address addr
  on addr.address_id = cust.address_id
join city
  on city.city_id = addr.city_id
order by new_email;
```

Some cities have spaces, so they were replaced.

Comment: That's it! It works and makes sense, I really appreciate the help!
I'm currently working on sql quereys, do you know if there is like a discord server for questions because I'd say my question was quite easy and I don't want to spam stack with such "easy" questions.
And thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, I never used discord for such things. But wouldn't be surprised if there were.  Well, the internet doesn't lack information about Sql.

Comment: when seeing `lower(...`, i wanted to point to this question/answer: [Are email addresses case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807909/are-email-addresses-case-sensitive)

Comment: @Luuk From what I understand, [the domain name is case-insensitive by convention](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt). But the rest, that depends on the mailing system. Most probably treat it case-insensitive though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql `concat` function to concatenate those columns into an email.

```
concat(first_name, '.', last_name, '@', city, '.com')
```

You also need to remove whitespaces from all involved column to generate valid emails using the `replace` function.

Knowing this, just join the three tables customer,   address and city to get all the needed columns.

```
select first_name, last_name, 
concat(REPLACE(first_name, ' ', ''), '.', REPLACE(last_name, ' ', ''), '@', REPLACE(city, ' ', ''), '.com') as email
from customer c inner join address a on c.address_id = a.address_id
inner join city ct on a.city_id = ct.city_id
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=c0c4f772f10d6ed5c705779c1d9048f3)