# Liferay storing user email address in all lower case

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am creating an user in liferay with the email address 'ABCD@domain.com' but when checked in the USER_ table in liferay database its store as 'abcd@domain.com'.  I am using below API

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(creatorUserId,
                            companyId, autoPassword, password1, password2,
                            autoScreenName, screenName, usernameoremail, facebookId,
                            openId, Locale.ENGLISH, usernameoremail,
                            StringPool.BLANK, StringPool.BLANK, prefixId, suffixId,
                            male, birthdayMonth, birthdayDay, birthdayYear,
                            jobTitle, groupIds, organizationIds, roleIds,
                            userGroupIds, sendEmail, serviceContext);
```

at this point we are sure that email is in the form which we had sent.

Any idea why this is happenning? Any property in portal-ext which we can use to store it as is?

Comment: Why is it a Problem?

Comment: Not sure this will help you, but still have a look : https://web.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+CAS/maximized#section-Developing+a+CAS-Sample+Authenticator+-+LiferayAuth+(Matching+the+modified+AuthPipeline)

Comment: @Jens it can be a problem because the part before the @ (local mailbox part) can be case sensitive (even though not sure there are any mail servers that do enforce it)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807909/are-email-addresses-case-sensitive - while case-sensitivity in the local-part seems to be legal, it's safe to assume that it is unused due to broken handling everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any email address you give, to create a user, it would be converted to lowercase in UserLocalServiceImpl.addUserWithWorkflow(). There isn't any configuration to change this behavior. Personally, I do not see the significant of lowercase here.

Answer (score 1):

As per the given post [Are email address case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807909/are-email-addresses-case-sensitive) even though as per the spec RFC 5321, section-2.3.11:Part of the email address before @ is supposed to be case-sensitive,but it is not handled that way by most of the mail service providers,and hence it stored in that fashion by liferay too.You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013726/did-capitals-ever-matter-in-email-addresses)  too.
There is no property to handle email case sensivity.